# Windows automatically create download's children folders on desktop

Tags: windows-7

My computer is a bit slow. So I tried to clean its registry. However, after some registry files had been removed, I got an error that all folders inside folder `Downloads` (`Compressed,Documents,Music,Programs,Video`) are automatically created on desktop right after Windows started. If I delete these folders, Windows will recreate them on starting.

How could I fix it?

Comment: Restore the registry from the backup you made before you began hacking away critical keys

Answer (score 1):

Those are called "Libraries" by Microsoft and "guarded", their location on your desktop are either true moves or your viewing shortcut links to their default locations.

You're allowed to drag and drop the Libraries to a new location or right click the library and the menus include a "Location" configuration.

Your Desktop Library starts at c:\users***YourUserID***Desktop but can always be pinpointed using a variable capable of locating the directory similar to forwarded postal mail with this parameter:

%userprofile%\desktop

Your registry cleaner, whichever tool used can be effective but relying solely on the tool to backup your configuration before making changes is driving without a net.